# Webapp fails with "JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed" after adding a maven dependency to hadoop-azure

Tags: maven, jboss, jersey, azure-web-app-service, resteasy

I have a webapp that runs fine in JBoss EAP 6.4.  I want to add some functionality to my webapp so that it can process Parquet files that reside in AzureBlob storage.  I add a single dependency to my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-azure</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

If I now try to start my webapp, it fails at start up:

> 09:29:43,703 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
> 1-10) MSC000001: Failed to start service
> jboss.deployment.unit."myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE:
> org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
> jboss.deployment.unit."myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE:
> JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment
> "myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"    at
> org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166)
> [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]     at
> org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
> [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
> ... Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
> JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig
> com.mycompany.myapp.rest.RestApplication
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter
> com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig   at
> org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scan(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:206)
> at
> org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:104)
> at
> org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159)
> [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]     ...
> 5 more
>
> 09:29:43,709 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
> (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed -
> address: ([("deployment" => "myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure
> description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
> {"jboss.deployment.unit."myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE" =>
> "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
> jboss.deployment.unit."myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE:
> JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment
> "myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
> Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
> JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig
> com.mycompany.myapp.rest.RestApplication
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter
> com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig"}}

The message "JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed" seems to be caused by my webapp trying to use both RestEasy and Jersey.  JBoss uses RestEasy by default.  Apparently, hadoop-azure must have a Jersey application class.  How can I eliminate this problem by indicating that I don't want to use the Jersey-based application class?

Comment: Can you try to use the most recent `hadoop-azure` and see what happens. In the version you are using, `hadoop-common` is `compile` and newer versions it is `provided`. `hadoop-common` is what pulls in Jersey.

Comment: I updated hadoop-azure to 3.3.0 (and also tried 3.2.2), but still got "JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed".  I've updated the question to show 3.3.0.

Comment: Problem solved!  My pom.xml also had an entry for hadoop-common with a scope of "compile".  When I changed that to "provided", my app ran in JBoss. @Paul - if you write up your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.  If you don't feel like it, I'll write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hadoop-azure` pulls in `hadoop-common`, which pulls in Jersey. In the version of `hadoop-azure` you're using, `hadoop-common` is in `compile` `<scope>`. In new version, it is in `provided` scope. So you can just upgrade the `hadoop-azure` dependency to the latest one. If you need `hadoop-common` to compile, then you can redeclare `hadoop-common` and put it in `provided` scope.