# Need strategy for identifying root cause of "JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed"

Tags: rest, maven, jboss, jersey, resteasy

I have a problem similar to my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67807156/webapp-fails-with-jbas011232-only-one-jax-rs-application-class-allowed-after).  I have a webapp that runs fine in JBoss EAP 6.4. I want to add some functionality to my webapp so that it can manipulate a hive-metastore. I add a single dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If I now try to start my webapp, it fails at start up:

> 15:07:37,718 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
> 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service
> jboss.deployment.unit."myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE:
> org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
> jboss.deployment.unit."myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE:
> JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment
> "myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
> ...  Caused by:
> org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
> JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed.
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.DeferredResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClassNamesResourceConfig
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig
> com.mycompany.RestApplication
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ApplicationAdapter
> com.sun.jersey.api.core.ClasspathResourceConfig

The message "JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed" seems to be caused by my webapp trying to use both RestEasy (v. 2.3.10.Final-redhat-1) and Jersey. JBoss uses RestEasy by default. Apparently, hive-jdbc must directly or indirectly have a Jersey application class.

I would like to eliminate this problem by indicating that I don't want to use a Jersey-based application class.  What strategy can I employ to discover where that Jersey-based class exists?  If I generate the dependency tree with mvn,

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree -Dverbose=true
```

hive-jdbc has nearly 800 lines of dependencies.  There must be a better strategy than looking through the source code of all of the dependencies.  Or, is there somehow a way to tell JBoss to ignore Jersey application classes?

BTW, unlike my previous question, hadoop-common doesn't seem to be the culprit.  When I look at the occurrences of "hadoop-common" in the dependency tree, I see the following:

[image: hadoop common occurrences]

My current strategy goes like this:

```
Repeat
    add exclusion to likely looking package in pom file
    start JBoss and examine console log
    if console log has no JBAS01132 error then
        if console log has no startup failure due to NoClassDefFound error then
            Done!
        else remove exclusion
until Done
```

I can't get to "done".  At this point, I seem to be stuck on the `jersey-server` package.  Without it being present, we get the `NoClassDefFound` error.  With it, we get `JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed`.

Comment: Do you know what version of RESTEasy you are using?

Comment: Just digging through the Hadoop repository, it seems like Hadoop makes heavy use of Jersey. So I don't think removing Jersey is an option. My guess about RESTEasy is that it has a ServletContainerIntializer that grabs all the Application implementations. I know RESTEasy can be run without a servlet initializer. It will require you to manually register all your resource classes and manually register the Application class. This means that you will not be able to use an empty Application class for configuration. This is just a guess though.

Comment: @Paul Samsotha - RestEasy v. 2.3.10.Final-redhat-1 is what we use.  I'm adding the version information to the question.

Comment: I don't think that version makes use of a servlet initializer, so it's something else.

Comment: To find where Jersey is being used you can use `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.glassfish.jersey,org.glassfish.jersy.*`.

Comment: Thanks, James.  That narrows the potential scope of the problem to 28 usages of Jersey jars.  However, the first part of my problem is determining which of those usages causes the JBAS011232 messages, the next part of my problem being to figure out how to work around the conflict(s).

Comment: I'd fetch the Jersey sources, fire up the debugger and check where the exception is thrown. There you should be able to get more information about that class name and with that information it should be quite easy to grep it within your dependency graph.